# Django ORM: avoid multiple queries when saving models with foreign key relationships

Tags: python, django, performance, django-models, orm

Let's suppose I have 3 models: **A**, **B**, **C**, with **C** having foreign keys relationship with both **A** and **B**.
How can I avoid multiple queries, when saving a **C** model if I have the necessary info to retrieve **A** and **B**?

Currently my code is something like:

```
a = A.objects.get(title='the title', platform='the platform')
b = A.objects.get(id='the id')
C.objects.update_or_create(a=a, b=b, defaults={'c_param_1':'value'})
```

this sucks, since it executes at least 3 queries (4 if the C object does not exist).
I would like to retrieve **a** and **b** at the db layer... how can be implemented using Django's ORM?

I currently tried to use Q objects in this way:

```
C.objects.update_or_create(
        a=Q(a__title='the title') & Q(a__platform='the platform'), 
        b=Q(b__id='the id'), 
        c_param_1='value'
)
```

But I get:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Q'
```

ps: I'm using Django 1.7

Answer (score 1):

Well, since foreign key is actually id of object it's refferring to, you have to run a query to get this id. But if you already have id of parent object you can create a child object w/o fully loading parent:

```
C.objects.update_or_create(
    a_id=id_of_a, 
    b_id=id_of_b,
    c_param_1='value'
)
```